# Watir and <script>

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am very new to programming so trying to solve the following issue with Watir:

I have a webpage that is full of  fields, I'm trying to scrape values from inside  ==$. The values inside start from var pageData if that helps.

X path is //*[@id="innerpage"]/script[48]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `==$` means or what `var pageData` means, but to get the element at the provided XPath you use:

```
element = browser.element(id: 'innerpage').script(index: 47)
```

Though hopefully there's something more unique you can use than just the 48th script element.

From there you get the information at the element as desired:

```
element.text
element.value
element.attribute(attribute_name)
```

Comment: ==$ I meant the element says (<script>==$). Can you explain how do I do I get information from the element?

Comment: I tried to just use "puts element.text" after your element command and I get nothing. Sorry I am really new to this and struggling to find manuals for script and elements :( Just to add, the element in question is JavaScript

Comment: Ah, yes the fact that it is a script element might be making it weird. Try `#inner_html` instead of `#text`.

Comment: last question... Do I have to use Watir for this? Can this be done in non browser?

Comment: You can try grabbing the content of the page using an html library like open-uri and parsing it with nokogiri, but it obviously isn't going to execute any javascript if that's important to what you are parsing.

Comment: got it, last stupid question... how can I just return certain text from the inner_html? For example there are couple values like color:, size: etc... I want to only see information thats together with color or size etc. How would I achieve that

Comment: I would need to see an example to provide more specific assistance on that. I think the original question has been answered, we can continue this conversation in the #watir channel of the Selenium Slack group if you'd like: http://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Without seeing the site in question, and the resulting HTML, it's very difficult for anyone to advise you on how to scrape data from the site (presuming you have permission to do that, and it does not violate their terms of service)      if you want assistance with that I'd suggest you start a new question  a sample of the site HTML that contains the information you are trying to get (if you right-click where the info appears in the browser, and use inspect, then include the HTML around the thing you want) it would help.  Or include a marked-up screenshot and a link to the site.